# When I use DataGridRow for Getting data from selected row content, Null data is returned always

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I use WPF Metro datagrid.
When I use DataGridRow for Getting data from selected row content,
Always Null data is returned at var 'rowview'.
What is my problem?

This is my code.

```
    private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IInputElement element = e.MouseDevice.DirectlyOver;
        if (element != null && element is FrameworkElement)
        {
            if (((FrameworkElement)element).Parent is DataGridCell)
            {
                DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
                if (grid != null && grid.SelectedItems != null && grid.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
                {
                    DataGridRow rowview = grid.SelectedItem as DataGridRow;
                    if (rowview != null)
                    {
                        ProjectInfo addJobWindow = new ProjectInfo();
                        addJobWindow.ShowDialog();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    <DataGrid x:Name="DgProjectInfo" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"
```

AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="-11,11,211,-1" 
MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" IsReadOnly="True">

Comment: u sure u wanna check rowView != null ? you are not using rowView anyway ? just check is grid.selectedItem != null.... rest read ans below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert grid.SelectedItem as DataGridRow. Refer the below code to get the datagrid row.

```
DataGridRow rowview = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(grid.SelectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `grid.SelectedItem` isn't a `DataGridRow`?
You can check by mousing over the property "SelectedItem" and reading the prompt.

You could also type:

```
var temp = grid.SelectedItem;
```

and add a breakpoint after this line to easily determine the type.